# Displaying the sum just in one row

Tags: php, mysql

I hav this sql query:

```
$sql = "SELECT (SELECT SUM(total_pay) FROM workers) total,workers. * FROM workers WHERE projects_id = ".$id;
```

And I want to display data into table rows:

```
$stmt = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysqli_errno($con));
<?php while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)){ ?>
    <form action="update_del.php" method="post">
    <th>Payments</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Project</th>
    <th width="25%">Delete</th>

    <tr>

      <?php while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)){ ?>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['total_pay']?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['date_of_pay']?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $name['project_name'] ?></td>
      <td align="center"><!--<input class="imgClass_insert" type="submit" name="submit1" value="" />-->
        <input class="imgClass_dell" type="submit" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" name="delete_workers" value=""/>


    </td>
  </tr>

    </tr>

  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">Total <?php echo $name['project_name']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['total'] ?></td>
  </tr>
    <?php } ?>

</table>
```

The problem is, that the sum of the payment is repeated with every row displayed, so how can I display the sum query just once in the end of the table ? Should put it in a single query specified for the sum only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either remove the `total` from your query and use PHP to calculate, or you can just simply store the total and use it outside your `while` statement. Something like

```
<?php 

$total = 0;
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)){ 

  $total = $rows['total'];

  ?>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['total_pay']; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['date_of_pay']; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $name['project_name']; ?></td>
    <td align="center">
      <!--<input class="imgClass_insert" type="submit" name="submit1" value="" />-->
      <input class="imgClass_dell" type="submit" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" name="delete_workers" value=""/>   
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>

<tr>
  <td colspan="3">Total <?php echo $name['project_name']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $total; ?></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Though since you're traversing all the results anyway it would be best to remove it from the SQL and calculate it.

`$sql = "SELECT workers.* FROM workers WHERE projects_id = ".$id;`

```
<?php 

$total = 0;
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)){ 

  $total += $rows['total_pay'];
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['total_pay']; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $rows['date_of_pay']; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $name['project_name']; ?></td>
    <td align="center">
      <!--<input class="imgClass_insert" type="submit" name="submit1" value="" />-->
      <input class="imgClass_dell" type="submit" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" name="delete_workers" value=""/>   
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>

<tr>
  <td colspan="3">Total <?php echo $name['project_name']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $total; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: To ensure decimal accuracy, you should use intval() when you add, like this:    $total += intval($rows['total_pay']);

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem properly, then this might help you to generate sum in the last rows as you require.

```
"SELECT total_pay, date_of_pay,project_name
 FROM workers WHERE project_id=".$id."
UNION
 SELECT 'ALL', SUM(total_pay)
 FROM workers";
```